# docRef.getDocument(as: ...) failing to compile?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've written some code which is almost identical to the Firebase Firestore docs, but using a User class that I defined (which uses the Codable prototype).

```swift
    let docRef = db.collection(USER_COLLECTION).document(UID)
    
    var returnVal : User?
    
    // The line below is where the errors pop up
    docRef.getDocument(as: User.self) { result in
        switch result {
        case .success(let user):
            // A Book value was successfully initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
            returnVal = user
        case .failure(let error):
            // A Book value could not be initialized from the DocumentSnapshot.
            // self.errorMessage = "Error decoding document: \(error.localizedDescription)"
            returnVal = nil
        }
    }
```

When writing it, xcode always helps autocomplete the function and I can navigate and find the source code in my project, but as soon as I try to build the project, it gives me three errors:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'User.Type' to expected argument type 'FirestoreSource'
Contextual closure type '(DocumentSnapshot?, Error?) -> Void' expects 2 arguments, but 1 was used in closure body
Incorrect argument label in call (have 'as:_:', expected 'source:completion:')
```

to me it looks like it is not recognizing the extension to `FirebaseFirestore` defined in `FirebaseFirestoreSwift`, but I have all those modules included and the pods installed.

I have tried using the other function signature:

```
docref.getDocument { (result,error) in ...}
```

and it didn't immediately give any errors. However, I would prefer to use the way made available with the firestore swift extensions as shown in the docs.
Any help is greatly appreciated!!

EDIT:
Here is the definition for the user class too:

```swift
class User : Codable {
    var screenName : String!
    @DocumentID var UID : String? = UUID().uuidString
    var pronouns : String = ""
    var personalItemCatalogueID : String!
    var householdIDs : [String] = []

    init (UID _uid : String){
        UID = _uid
    }

    init (screenName _sn : String, UID _uid : String, pronouns _pronouns : String, personalItemCatalogueID _picID : String, householdIDs _hIDs : [String]) {
        screenName = _sn
        UID = _uid
        pronouns = _pronouns
        personalItemCatalogueID = _picID
        householdIDs = _hIDs
    }

    func updateDB() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let docRef = db.collection(USER_COLLECTION).document(self.UID!)
        do {
            try docRef.setData(from: self)
        }
        catch {
            // TODO: More error handling
            print(error)
        }
    }

    func addToDB() {
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        let collectionRef = db.collection(USER_COLLECTION)
        do {
            let newDocReference = try collectionRef.addDocument(from: self)
             print("User stored with new document reference: \(newDocReference)")
        }
        catch {
            // TODO: Better error handling
            print(error)
        }
    }

}
```

Edit 2:
In case there's an issue with my podfile, here it is:

```rb
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '15.3.1'

def shared_pods
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
end

target 'PocketHome' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for PocketHome
  shared_pods

end

target 'PocketHomeTests' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for PocketHome
  shared_pods

end
```

Comment: What versions of the pods are installed? Check the Podfile.lock file.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This sounds like an outdated version of Firebase issue as mentioned above. If not, can you update your question with how your `User` class is defined?

Comment: The versions of the pods are `- FirebaseFirestore (1.19.0):` and  `- FirebaseFirestoreSwift (0.4.0):`

Answer (score 1):

Turned out this was an issue with the version of firebase firestore that I had in my project. I was able to fix this by updating my podfile to require the latest version of Firebase Firestore and Firebase Firestore Swift

```rb
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '13.0'

def shared_pods
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '8.13.0'
  pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift', '8.13.0-beta'
end

target 'PocketHome' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for PocketHome
  shared_pods

end

target 'PocketHomeTests' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for PocketHome
  shared_pods

end
```